# Reflecting a coordinate in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Ive been working on a platformer with a specific mechanic that allows the player to "mirror" itself onto the other side. Think of this:

The circle when E is pressed would go from here

[image: Before]

To here afterwards, the exact same position from the splitting platform but in this case mirrored.

[image: After]

Therefore, trying to implement this, I came up with an equation that should factor in a platform I set up that splits the two areas. and teleport the player to the exact mirror position based on screen size.

To mirror the position from the top, I wrote this, it takes the screen height (523 to be exact) and subtracts it from the height of the two sections (260 pixels) subtracted by the position of the player.

```
player.pos.y =  screenSize - (260 - player.pos.y)
```

And to mirror on the bottom half, this function which just subtracts the position by the height of the sections plus 3.

```
player.pos.y = player.pos.y - 263
```

The only issue is that when on the ground or in the air, it teleports you to a completely incorrect area nowhere near where you once were. Think around basically the edge of the screen, this also occurs when teleporting from the bottom section.

[image: What is going on]

Because of the odd method coordinates work in pygame, I cant use standard reflection methods used in geometry, is there a method to do a reflection with a coordinate system like pygames?

Comment: What do you mean by "the odd method coordinates work"?  It's a straightforward Cartesian system.  Also, note that your two equations (upper and lower) are algebraically identical.

Comment: Oh. Well I meant that since the screen was not divided into four quadrants, and negative coordinates are in the other direction, I cant just make the players position negative like a normal reflection formula across the Y axis, for that would make the character go off screen. I tried to create the two equasions so they would work and in hand because the top equasion did not work with the bottom for some reason. @Prune

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're doing this with reference to the entire screen, rather than the mirror: you've reflected across the center line, regardless of the mirror's position.

You want the `new` position to be as far from the `mirror` as the `old`, but in the opposite direction.  Thus, we get this derivation, solving for the `new` coordinate:

> new - mirror = mirror - old
>
> new = 2 * mirror - old

See how *that* works for you.

---

UPDATE

Substituting your variables , and assuming a mirror object:

```
player.pos.y = 2 * mirror.pos.y - player.pos.y
```

Comment: What does the mirror variable stand for?

Comment: The x-coordinate of the mirror.

Comment: Gotcha, so 0 then. Also im a little confused about that top line of code there, I get an error for it `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`. And im assuming that new stands for the players Y coords.

Comment: Another issue is that for it does not work with the bottom, the player just flips gravity and falls down off the screen. Can you fill this code in a bit more? Its too vague @Prune

Comment: That's an algebraic derivation, not Python code.  Use the second line only.

Comment: Correction on previous comment: `mirror` is the **y**-coordinate of the mirror, not the x.

Comment: .-. Well that makes more sense.

Comment: You don't; it's an algebraic equation, not Python code.  The second line happens to be both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169198/discussion-between-prune-and-pygasm).

Comment: Why did you leave?

Comment: Huge realization, the teleport on the bottom only works if you jump. When directly on the platform it is incredibly glitchy.